# PostgreSQL: concatenation of pg_sleep

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection

There's this challenge from portswigger: https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/blind/lab-time-delays

I noticed that these 2 solutions work:
`' || pg_sleep(10)--` , `' || (SELECT pg_sleep(10)--`

But this doesn't: `' || SELECT pg_sleep(10)--`

And my question is what's the different between with and without `()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Because](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) This is the syntax of the SQL:

> A scalar subquery is an ordinary SELECT query **in parentheses** that returns exactly one row with one column.

Comment: So basically `|| select` is trying to concatenate with the statement itself, and `|| (select...)` is trying to concatenate with the return value?

Comment: No, `|| SELECT` is impossible syntax. It has no meaning at all.